# get a nested element inside a div by class name

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get an **span** element which has a class of **main-tag** inside a nested *div*. But i don't want to get that element through *querySelector* as there are many elements in my html file with the same class and i don't intend to use IDs for that.

I know i am making some mistake in my recursive function. That's why this code is not working.

So for this i'm recursively calling a function to get the desired element. But *undefined* is returned by **found** variable.

```js
function getElem(cell, name) {
  let found;
  if (cell.classList.contains(name)) return cell;
  else if (cell.children.length === 0) return null;
  else {
    found = Array.from(cell.children).find((element) =>
      element.classList.contains(name)
    );
    if (found === undefined) {
      Array.from(cell.children).forEach((element) => {
        found = getElem(element, name);
      });
    } else return found;
  }
}


console.log(getElem(document.getElementById("block-one"), "main-tag"));
```

```html
<div id="block-one">
  <div class="something-one">
    <span class="something-two">Hello</div>
    <span class="abc">not found</div>
  </div>
  <div class="here">
    <span class="main-tag">Yes, i am here</div>
    <span class="bogus-tag">never find out</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML in the question is missing an ending `"` on an attribute. Is that also true of your  actual HTML? It may be messing up your structure.

Comment: I made you a snippet and added a missing `"` on the abc class

Comment: Please post actual valid HTML

Comment: Your markup is using `</div>` where `</span>` is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup is using `</div>` where `</span>` is expected.

You can use full CSS selectors with `querySelector`. So for instance, to find the first element with the class `main-tag` inside the element with `id="block-one"`, you can do this:

```
const element = document.querySelector("#block-one .main-tag");
```

Live Example:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#block-one .main-tag"));
```

```html
<div id="block-one">
  <div class="something-one">
    <span class="something-two">Hello</span>
    <span class="abc">not found</span>
  </div>
  <div class="here">
    <span class="main-tag">Yes, i am here</span>
    <span class="bogus-tag">never find out</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or alternatively, you can call `querySelector` on an element to only look at its descendants:

```
const element = document.getElementById("block-one").querySelector(".main-tag");
```

Live Example:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("block-one").querySelector(".main-tag"));
```

```html
<div id="block-one">
  <div class="something-one">
    <span class="something-two">Hello</span>
    <span class="abc">not found</span>
  </div>
  <div class="here">
    <span class="main-tag">Yes, i am here</span>
    <span class="bogus-tag">never find out</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

A key difference between those is that the second one will throw an error if there is no `id="block-one"` element; the first will just return `null`. You could fix that using the newish optional chaining operator:

```
const element = document.getElementById("block-one")?.querySelector(".main-tag");
```

`element` will be either A) The matching element if there is one; B) `null` if there's an `id="block-one"` element but there are no `.main-tag` elements in it; or C) `undefined` if there is no `id="block-one"` element at all. (Even though `document.getElementById` returns `null` when it doesn't find something, the optional chaining operator results in `undefined` when its left-hand operand is either `undefined` or `null`.)

Or just use the `document.querySelector` option (the first one above), which gives you the matching element or `null`.

---

You don't seem to want this from your HTML, but: If you want to allow for the possibility the element itself has the class (`getElem` seems to allow for that possibility), you can use a group selector:

```
const element = document.querySelector("#block-one.main-tag, #block-one .main-tag");
```

Live Example:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#block-one.main-tag, #block-one .main-tag"));
```

```html
<div id="block-one" class="main-tag">
  <div class="something-one">
    <span class="something-two">Hello</span>
    <span class="abc">not found</span>
  </div>
  <div class="here">
    <span class="main-tag">Yes, i am here</span>
    <span class="bogus-tag">never find out</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

That works because the first member of the group, `#block-one.main-tag` (without a space) only matches the `id="block-one"` element if it has the class. If `block-one` doesn't have the class but one of its descendants does, that's found by the other member of the group, `#block-one .main-tag` (with the space). If the `block-one` element has the class **and** one of its descendants does, the `block-one` element is the one found, since it's first in document order (a parent is before its children in document order).

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid.

When fixed, you can get the span using selectors directly

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#block-one > div.here > span.main-tag").textContent)
```

```html
<div id="block-one">
  <div class="something-one">
    <span class="something-two">Hello</span>
    <span class="abc">not found</span>
  </div>
  <div class="here">
    <span class="main-tag">Yes, I am here</span>
    <span class="bogus-tag">never find out</span>
  </div>
</div>
```